# Binomial distribution convergence

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients

Let $Y \sim\binom{n}{\pi}$
Suppose $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\pi \rightarrow 0$ such that $n\pi \rightarrow \mu$, where $\mu$ is a constant. derive the limiting distribution of Y.

$f_Y(y)= \binom{n}{y}\pi^y(1-\pi)^{n-y}$

I am thinking if this is 0 since the $\pi^y$ term converges to 0?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i just posted it

Comment: OK. Now, if there is convergence to a distribution, it cannot be zero since zero is not a distribution. You might want to study more carefully the behaviour of each $f_Y(y)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: so when it converges to infinity it will become normal right?

Comment: No - it has mean $\mu$ and variance $\mu(1-\pi)$, and in the limit a variance of $\mu$.  But a normal distribution with these parameters would have a positive probability of giving negative values.

Comment: wait no I got through to here $f_Y(y)= \frac{n!}{(n-y)!y!} \pi^y(1-\pi)^{n-y}$ and im thinking how to get through to the next step..... but i dunno how to proceed after the fraction term becomes 1/y!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not converging to $0$ since
\begin{equation}
f_Y(y)= \binom{n}{y}\pi^y(1-\pi)^{n-y} \approx\frac{1}{y!}\left(\frac{n\pi}{1-\pi}\right)^y(1-\pi)^n
\rightarrow\frac{\mu^y}{y!}e^{-\mu}
\end{equation}

Comment: Which is a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

Comment: $f_Y(y)= \frac{n!}{(n-y)!y!} \pi^y(1-\pi)^{n-y}$ so I got to here and the two infinity cancelled become 1/y! and i dunno how to proceed because i keep thinking the pi term becomes 0....

Comment: You're right $\pi$ closes to $0$. But, $\pi^n$ is not converging anymore because it is an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).